# GenericTabularInline with a ManyToMany Not Displaying Any Options

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-contenttypes

I attempt to add a GenericTabularInline to the admin of a related model and the ManyToMany field of the Generic Relation model does not display anything.

**models.py**

```
class RelatedIngredients(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, verbose_name='Content Type')
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Object ID')
    content_object = fields.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredients)
```

**admin.py**

```
class IngredientInline(GenericTabularInline):
    model = RelatedIngredients
    extra = 0
    min_num = 1
    max_num = 1
    can_delete = False
    fields = ['ingredients',]
    filter_horizontal = ['ingredients',]

@admin.register(Cake)
class CakeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     fields = ['name', 'description']
     inlines = [IngredientInline,]
```

The proper filter horizontal widget appears but it appears empty. Nothing in the available or chosen sides. Now I know the model works as I tried to do *RelatedIngredients.ingredients* as a Foreign Key and the GenericTabularInline worked.

What's the difference? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you already added ingredients to select from? Try making an `Ingredients` admin and adding a few to your database and then looking at the `CakeAdmin` again.

Comment: Wow. That was silly of me. When I setup the new database I forgot to transfer the values over. All fixed! Thanks!